# Install Android App via USB

Tags: android, usb, installation

I've got a Problem. I am working on a Project where I am using a Programm on the PC to handle different data (which another programm = my android app creates), which i found on the plugged in sd-card of the android device.

My aim is now to use the programm on the Computer to install the Android App on the Android Device. In other words: My PC-Programm copies the .apk to the sd card of the Android Device via USB. But how can i install it now? I would be awesome if, after the copy-process has finished the app installs automatically.

Is something linke this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use ADB: http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f4/how-to-install-apps-using-adb-4482/

Available from
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: Well i also thought about using ADB but then i would have to install another programm. I want to do this directly with my PC-Program... if possible ;)

Comment: ADB can also push files to the SD card by the way, but you should probably provide some more background on why exactly you're trying to do all this.

Comment: Well... ok, I've got an Programm which runs on the Computer. (written in Java) It is responsible for the Connection with the plugged-in-Android-Device (via USB). So I now want to offer to option, that the User can click "Install my App" and then the PC-Programm copies the signed .apk to the (sdcard of the) device... afterwards the android-device should start the install-process automatically.

Comment: Your link is dead, and therefore your answer has become 99% useless.